# Trying to make linguistic sense of multiplication as scaling.

Tags: soft-question, arithmetic

I understand scaling of a number for it to be enlarged/shrunk by a scale factor/multiplier. Thus 3 scaled by a factor 2 means for it to become twice as big as itself. (2 units of 3 will be the new image instead of just the 1). For a factor 3 it'll be 3 times as big (3 units of 3), and for 4, 4 times as big.

However if 5 is scaled by a factor 1, that means for it to be made larger "one times" as itself which to me is translating as 5 being added to itself once. If 1 was to be scaled by a factor 5, that would mean to me that 1 was to be made 5 times larger (the new image will have 5 units of 1 instead of just 1).

I have this same confusion in 0 being scaled or something being scaled by 0 and also how negative scaling results in a negative with the same magnitude.

Sorry for the bundle of questions, I am trying to understand the scaling going on instead of the addition of multiples.

thanks

Comment: And why are you trying so hard to add confusion  to a well-understood, associative, (often) commutative and distributive (with addition) operation like multiplication? Mathematics is hard enough as it is, there's no need to make it still more obscure.

Comment: I am not "trying" to make it hard. That is exactly what I understand it to be and if it's an incorrect interpretation then I would like a better way to consider it. (scaling of an object, not multiplication itself).

Comment: No, you aren't just trying, you are succeeding. Interpreting multiplication as scaling (as you do in your title) in general is utterly wrong. Multiplication is multiplication. Scaling is a special case of multiplication of something (not a number, in general, more likely an element of some vector space, or a geometric figure, or...) by a scalar (and that's the **linguistic** reason why it's called **scalar**, by the way). So you have it almost right, just... upside down

Comment: When you scale by a factor of $1$, you should not add the original to the copy. When you scale by $5$, for example, you don't add the original either; you simply look at the result.

Comment: @Théophile then if the new image is 5 and the old was 1, then the old was made 5 times as large as 1. Can the 5 not be seen as the same result as have 5 quantities of 1 stacked in within each other?

Comment: Sure, if you like. This is fine for whole numbers. The point I was making is that when you multiply by 1, the new image is "1 quantity of 1", i.e., it's the same as before. You don't add it to the old one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd like you to focus on these two sentences:

> - Thus 3 scaled by a factor 2 means for it to become **twice as large as itself**.
> - However if 5 is scaled by a factor 1, that means for it to be made **one time larger than** (larger "one times" as) itself.

The first construction is unambiguous even when adapted to the degenerate case:

> 3 scaled by a factor 2 means for it to become *once as large as itself*.

I'd advise against using it at dinner with the Queen, though.

The second construction appears to be inherently ambiguous. See [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Is-there-any-difference-between-N-times-as-large-as-and-N-times-larger-than) or anything you can google out of "three times larger than".

Comment: Got it, many thanks that clears up the (n+1) thing. 

If 3 is scaled by a factor 1, it is to be made as large as itself once (that is to say, we're making 3 as large as how large 1 unit of 3 is).

If 3 is scaled by a factor 0, it is to be made as large as itself no times. (That quite literally is to say, it's NOT to be made bigger at all?)

In scaling of say, x by factor y, are we saying that x is being composed of itself "y times"?

Comment: @salman I wouldn't use the term "composed" (because in mathematics "composition" is something else, and in fact the composition of two scalings by $y$ would be a scaling by $y^2$). I'd stick to the usual "*sum of* $y$ *copies of* $x$".

Comment: ok so is it appropriate to say in the case 3 scaled by 6 that the new number (18) is as large as 6 multiples of 3 combined together. (Or is this a completely flawed way to consider scaling?). How is negative scaling done? We have (-1) to be scaled by 2, so it becomes twice as small as itself which is 2 multiples of (-1) combined together?